# Emission material + irradiance volume causing light to shine through solid objects? (And other issues)

Tags: eevee-render-engine, emission

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMXNs.jpg

I put my pictures on Imgur, because I only seemed to be able to add one photo to this post otherwise (I may have been doing it wrong, but all 3 are on imgur now anyway).

I have an emission material inside an engine jet 'bell', making a bright glow. Or trying to anyway, as the object only glows (bloom I guess) when the camera has the emission material in sight. When it's around a corner there's no bloom. Fine, add an irradiance volume.

However as you can see in the photos, the irradiance adds the correct 'bouncing glow' on the inside of the engine bells, but it also appears on other parts of the engine that -should- be in shadow. I can stop that happening by dropping the 'clipping end' of the irradiance to below about 1.5m, but as soon as I drop that low it ALSO stops making the inside of the engine bell glow.

Just to add, I have my materials set to 'opaque' for blending and shadows so they should be blocking light (as far as I know).

I assume I'm doing something wrong... I hope it's obvious (with the photos) what I'm trying to do and  the effect I'm going for. Is there maybe a better method in Eevee? Normal lights don't seem to work quite right, to get them to glow bright enough they seem to also glow through nearby materials, but perhaps I need to play with them more. Or maybe an emission volume, to get the 'glowing engine jet' type effect? Not sure if this is even a thing, as my last attempt at an emission volume did nothing at all haha.

Anyone with any suggestions or tips, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: Yeh I know how to add 'an' image. My problem was that I needed to add 3 of them. Which that post doesn't seem to help with. I solved it with imgur anyway, the link is in my question.